# A question about etymology of the Etruscan word for number eight

Tags: etymology, numbers, etruscan

An often cited etymology is that the Etruscan word ​​ (*kezp*, eight) is a compound word from ​ (*ki*, three) and  (*zep*, hand), that it meant literally "*three plus the number of fingers on a hand*". If so, why did ​ change to  in the first word and why did  disappear in the second?

More generally, is this etymology believed by most Etruscologists or only by those who try to connect Etruscan with some other ancient language and try to explain why the Etruscan word for the number eight looks nothing like the one in the language they are comparing Etruscan with?

Comment: Huh, I haven't come across that etymology before. Where have you seen it?

Comment: How do you get from "three hands" to "eight"?

Comment: @fdb Three plus the number of fingers on a hand.